# bulkinsert panda dataframe to postgresql with pyarrow

Tags: postgresql, dataframe, pyarrow

Please can someone advise as to how with pyarrow package we can insert the data of the dataframe to postgresql database table. We can do such operations with PG8000 or psycopg2 however my need here is with pyarrow.

Comment: There is currently no PostgreSQL integration available in the `pyarrow` package itself. See https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1058#issuecomment-626363009 for some pointers about current experiments to do this.

Comment: With pg8000 could you use the COPY command? https://github.com/tlocke/pg8000#copy-from-and-to-a-file